# rootScope functions in the .run module are not recognized

Tags: angularjs

I am testing an ionic app in my android phone. I'm using a rootScope function to check a user's session and this function shows a TypeError in the chrome debug console ("TypeError: $rootScope.checkSession is not a function") The closest that I could get to in my online search is this 
http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/08/16/Ionic-and-Cordovas-DeviceReady-My-Solution/
but I didn'nt quiet get the concept. I would be glad if you could assit. Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
forkapp.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $firebaseAuth, $firebase, $window, $ionicLoading) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    var fb = new Firebase("https://glowing-torch-9862.firebaseio.com/");
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    $rootScope.userEmail = null;
    $rootScope.baseUrl = 'https://glowing-torch-9862.firebaseio.com/';

    var authRef = new Firebase($rootScope.baseUrl);
    $rootScope.auth = $firebaseAuth(authRef);

    $rootScope.show = function(text) {
      $rootScope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
        content: text ? text : 'Loading..',
        animation: 'fade-in',
        showBackdrop: true,
        maxWidth: 200,
        showDelay: 0
      });
    };

    $rootScope.hide = function() {
      $ionicLoading.hide();
    };

    $rootScope.notify = function(text) {
      $rootScope.show(text);
      $window.setTimeout(function() {
        $rootScope.hide();
      }, 1999);
    };

    $rootScope.logout = function() {
      $rootScope.auth.$logout();
      $rootScope.checkSession();
    };

    $rootScope.checkSession = function() {
      var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(authRef, function(error, user) {
        if (error) {
          // no action yet.. redirect to default route
          $rootScope.userEmail = null;
          $window.location.href = '#/auth/signin';
        } else if (user) {
          // user authenticated with Firebase
          $rootScope.userEmail = user.email;
          $window.location.href = ('#/event');
        } else {
          // user is logged out
          $rootScope.userEmail = null;
          $window.location.href = '#/auth/signin';
        }
      });
    };
  }); //ionic platform ready
  })
```

Comment: Could be because `$rootScope.checkSession();` is used in `logout` before it was defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in `ionicPlatform.ready` event is executed and  `$rootScope.checkSession` function will be defined when Cordova's deviceready event fires, i.e., after Cordova's device APIs have loaded and are ready to access.

Generally `ionicPlatform.ready` is equal to `window.ready` event if you are running your ionic app in browser and your code will work. But it will take some time for `ionicPlatform.ready` event to be fired if you are running your app in a mobile device. Since you are defining `$rootScope.checkSession` function in `ionicPlatform.ready`, you have to call that function after deviceready event only.

A simple solution is define `$rootScope.checkSession` and other $rootScope functions outside of `ionicPlatform.ready`